# How to check if the laptop has infrared receiver in linux

Tags: hardware

I want to know if my laptop has infrared receiver in linux terminal. I was wondering if there is a terminal command that I can use to see if the laptop has an infrared receiver?

I know one way is to check if there is a dark glass part in front of it, but that's not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

`lshw` will show you the system's view of your hardware. `man lshw`.

You might have to `apt-cache search lshw` and `sudo apt-get install lshw`.

Comment: I know `sudo lshw -c network` shows network devices, but which class infrared belongs to?